# Returning a $promise from two resource calls in AngularJS to delay route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

## Use Case

Using a route provider, returning a $promise in the resolve will avoid the data popping up after the UI has loaded. However, I'm having trouble processing two different resource calls and returning it as a single array.

### Current Implementation

The current implementation works, but requires that the controller requires two resources.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/resource/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/resource.html',
      controller: ResourceController,
      resolve: {
        parentResource: function($route, SingleResource) {
          return SingleResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
        },
        childResources: function($route, ChildResource) {
          return ChildResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
        }
      }
  });
 });
```

However, what I'd like to do is provide `ResourceController` with a single array `Resource` that is an array composed of `parentResource` and `childResource` where item 0 in the array is the `parentResource`.

### Idea

This is what I have in mind, but I don't know what to return in the resolve? If I return result, the route will change and pass an empty array.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/resource/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/resource.html',
      controller: ResourceController,
      resolve: {
        Resource: function($route, SingleResource) {
          var resources = [];
          SingleResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id })
            .$promise.then(function(parent)
                             { resources.splice(0, 0, parent); })
                     .catch(function(error) { alert('error!'); })
          ChildResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id })
            .$promise.then(function(children) 
                             { resources = resources .concat(children); })
                     .catch(function(error) { alert('error!'); })

          return ???? // Can I return a $promise here?
        }
      }
  });
});
```

### Question

How can I get my ResourceController signature from
The idea is then to get the controller to have this signature:

```
var ResourceController = function($scope, parentResource, childResources) { ... }
```

to

```
var ResourceController = function($scope, resources) { ... }
```

through returning $promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $q.all to return an array of promises

```
var resources = [];

resources.push(SingleResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise);
resources.push(ChildResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise);

return $q.all(resources) // You return an array of promises
```

Comment: Precisely it is a **new** promise which combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when **all** of the input promises are resolved.

Comment: Yes, true. I was convinced it would return an array. But you are absolutely correct, it does return one promise when all original promises have been resolved. Wouldn't make sense to return an array. Upvoted!

Comment: @AntónioSérgioSimões It works great. Using the $q.all(resources).then(...) I was able to flatten the results to return a one dimensional array.

Answer (score -1):

Try with like

```
 resolve: {
                parentResource: function($route, SingleResource) {
                  return SingleResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
                },
                childResources: function($route, ChildResource,  parentResource) {
                  return  (parentResource.length > 0) ? ChildResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise : [];
                }
              }
```

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/a2fcbf874a1c

Comment: and if the childResource's promise is resolved before the parent one because the server was quicker on that one ? This will randomly work check the accepted answer.