# How to check if all async operations have finished using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I got three different functions that make $http calls. The three functions are called one after the other.

Is there any way to know when all of them have finished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a $promise from two resource calls in AngularJS to delay route change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432938/returning-a-promise-from-two-resource-calls-in-angularjs-to-delay-route-change)

Comment: I just asked this question today! :) $q.all() is what you want.

Comment: Yep. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432938/returning-a-promise-from-two-resource-calls-in-angularjs-to-delay-route-change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). You can use `$q.all(promises)` to combine multiple promises in one new promise. The new promise is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.